# How do you apply a function to all values in selected cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was entering timesheet data (in minutes) into an Excel spreadsheet.  Then the requirements changed - the data actually needs to be in hours.  Is there a way to divide all the cells by 60 **in place** without using formulas?  Ideally, I'd like to select all the cells and somehow say "Divide by 60."

*Note: I've answered my own question in the hopes that others might find it useful (or provide a better solution!).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out you can do exactly what I wanted:

1. Enter the number 60 into another cell, doesn't matter where.
2. Copy that cell (ctrl-C).
3. Select the cells you want to modify.
4. Right-click, paste special.
5. You get some options of what operation you want to apply.  I
   picked Divide for my case.
6. Magic!  All the selected cells' values are now divided by 60.  You
   can even delete the cell you used for the number 60.

Comment: Looks like that if you didn't post your question there would be no need to ask it, since you found the answer in a matter of seconds.  :o)

Comment: @Mario, yeah I was trying to follow the SE guidelines of "pretend you're on Jeopardy" when answering your own question.  I had already found the solution and thought others might benefit from it.

Comment: Self-answering is fine on these sites.